# How to break from a asyncio sleep in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am very new to `asyncio`.

How do I break out of `asyncio.sleep(secs)`?

```
def onPendingTickers(tickers):
    for t in tickers:
         print(t)

    tz = pytz.timezone('America/Mexico_City')
    if datetime.now(tz).time() >= datetime.strptime('13:30', '%H:%M').time():
        ib.disconnect()
        print('breaking')

ib.pendingTickersEvent += onPendingTickers
ib.sleep(5*60)
conn.close()
ib.pendingTickersEvent -= onPendingTickers
```

```
ib.sleep(5*60)

#is where I can't figure out how to break out of
#in case time is above particular time.
```

The `sleep` function:

```
def sleep(secs: float = 0.02) -> bool:
    """
    Wait for the given amount of seconds while everything still keeps
    processing in the background. Never use time.sleep().

    Args:
        secs (float): Time in seconds to wait.
    """
    run(asyncio.sleep(secs))
    return True
```

How do I break out of the `ib.sleep()`?

Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: `asyncio.run` blocks, so your function will work exactly like `time.sleep()`. You can only sleep asynchronously in async functions.